# Node js requiring a file that is 2 directories back

Tags: node.js

> SteamBot_Csgo_Bot\settings\Configuration

i have a js file in configuration folder and want to call a file in the steamBot_Csgo_Bot folder

i understand that ../ goes back one how do i go back 2 directories

Comment: CS:GO bots are against Steam ToS, just saying.

Comment: `../../` is how to go back 2 directories anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go 2 directories back with the following 
    `../../`

Answer (score 0):

Use ../ twice.

```
../../jsfile.js
```